# Why does running compute() on a filtered Dask dataframe take so long?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm reading in data using this:
`ddf1 = dd.read_sql_table('mytable', conn_string, index_col='id', npartitions=8)`

Of course, this runs instantaneously due to lazy computation. This table has several hundred million rows.

Next, I want to filter this Dask dataframe:

`ddf2 = ddf1.query('some_col == "converted"')`

Finally, I want to convert this to a Pandas dataframe. The result should only be about 8000 rows:

`ddf3 = ddf2.compute()`

However, this is taking very long (~1 hour). Can I get any advice on how to substantially speed this up? I've tried using `.compute(scheduler='threads')`, changing up the number of partitions, but none have worked so far. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because it's doing a lot of work, presumably?

Comment: Forgive me if I had the wrong impression, but I thought Dask was supposed to speed things up like this substantially?

Comment: Possibly. What alternative have you compared it to? Several hundred-million rows is a lot of data. What is exactly is your setup? A computing cluster? Or your laptop? `dask` isn't *magic*.

Comment: I'm comparing it to simply loading the entire table into memory via Pandas. My setup is my laptop that has four cores, but I have also tried this on an EC2 instance with high memory and i still exhibit similar performance issues, which leads me to believe I'm not doing the configuration properly

Comment: Well, how long does it take with just pandas? Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: It isn't possible because the size of the table exceeds memory capacity, so I haven't been able to do it.

I'm asking this question to get advice on better Dask configuration. I have many more computations I want to perform on the filtered dataframe, whether it be 8000 rows or 8 million rows and I don't want to deal with this in Pandas if I can use Dask for optimal performance before converting it to Pandas

Comment: The alternative is to query the same table a thousand times over, each time filtering for something different. Obviously this places a strain on the database, so my thinking was to load the entire table into Dask dataframe and perform separate filters on the Dask dataframe as needed

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you may be able to use sqlalchemy expression syntax to encode your filter clause in the query, and do the filtering server-side. If data transfer is your bottleneck, than that is your best solution, especially is the filter column is indexed.

Depending on your DB backend, sqlalchemy probably does not release the GIL, so your partitions cannot run in parallel in threads. All you are getting is contention between the threads and extra overhead. You should use the [distributed scheduler](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html) with processes.

Of course, *please* look at your CPU and memory usage; with the distributed scheduler, you also have access to the diagnostic dashboard. You should also be concerned with how big each partition will be in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reason I can't filter server-side is because I have thousands of filtering operations to perform, each on distinct subsets of the huge table. I should've made it clear that I am not only doing this filtering once. The idea is to load the entire table into Dask dataframe and perform separate filters on the Dask dataframe as needed instead of querying the database thousands of times over and straining the server.

I actually did try the distributed scheduler with processes on a remote EC2 server and it exhibited similar poor performance.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on partitioning with respect to the number of cores, threads, workers, etc?